# Digital Ocean, Ubuntu Droplet - make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: git, ubuntu, makefile, digital-ocean

I am using DigitalOcean to deploy my website. I chose the droplet to be ubuntu and followed the instructions to install git as mentioned here [How To Install Git on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04). I then reached the part where it says:

```
Now, you can make the package and install it by typing these two commands:

make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

I tried the command but I got `make: *** No rule to make target`all'.  Stop.` I googled around to check this issue so I found the following to install make:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I tried to use the make command again but I reached nothing. What else could be the problem?!

Comment: Why are you trying to install git from source?

Comment: @EtanReisner What's the problem with that?!

Comment: If you don't have a reason to do it then you can just follow the first section steps and install from a package and forget all about this bit.

Comment: I just followed the tutorial but I got stuck at the part explained in my question.

Comment: The tutorial has *two* ways to install git. The first uses `apt`. The second goes from source. If you followed the first `apt` part then you get to skip the "from source" part (though they don't make that as obvious as they probably should).

Comment: ok I got your point. Now, that I have it installed I am stuck from make part

Comment: You don't need the `make` bit **at all** if you've run the `apt` commands (from the first section) to install `git`. You already have it installed. You can just use it. You can go straight to the [How To Set Up Git](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04#how-to-set-up-git) section (it would be nice if the link on that page wasn't broken).

Answer (score 2):

> Requirements:
>   1.Install Putty http://www.putty.org/
>   2.Creat Droplet on Digital Ocean
>   3.You have created droplet on digital ocean and receive three things via Email (IP Adress, User Name and Password).

below link shows your requirements:
1. https://progtec.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/how-to-install-droplet-on-digital-ocean/

2. http://www.tutorsloop.net/app/live.php?id=4086720